# hi I have a question about triggers

Tags: trigger

I've written a code that prevents you from going back once the step has crossed in the opportunity stage. But it doesn't work. I don't know where it went wrong. Is there a way?

[image]

```java
trigger PreventStageBackward on Opportunity (before update) {
    for (Opportunity newOpp : Trigger.new) {
        Opportunity oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id);
        
        if (oldOpp.StageName != newOpp.StageName) {
            // Check if the new stage comes after the old stage in the stage order
            List<Schema.PicklistEntry> stageValues = Opportunity.StageName.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
            Boolean validTransition = false;
            Integer oldStageIndex = -1;
            Integer newStageIndex = -1;
            
            for (Integer i = 0; i < stageValues.size(); i++) {
                if (stageValues[i].getValue() == oldOpp.StageName) {
                    oldStageIndex = i;
                }
                if (stageValues[i].getValue() == newOpp.StageName) {
                    newStageIndex = i;
                }
            }
            
            if (oldStageIndex >= 0 && newStageIndex >= 0 && newStageIndex >= oldStageIndex) {
                validTransition = true;
            }
            
            if (!validTransition) {
                newOpp.StageName = oldOpp.StageName; // Revert the stage back to the old value
                newOpp.addError('Cannot move to a previous stage.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Stating "it doesn't work" is not enough to get an answer. Please edit the question adding the expected behavior. Moreover, if you just would like to prevent users going back to a previous stage, a validation rule is enough, you don't need a trigger.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a Map. You can assign values to the Map while defining it.
Something like the below code:

```
public Map<String, Integer> stageValue = new Map<String, Integer> {'Prospecting' => 1,
                                                                'Qualification' => 2,
                                                                'Needs Analysis' => 3, 
                                                                'Value Proposition' => 4, 
                                                                'Id. 'Decision Makers' => 5, 
                                                                'Perception Analysis' => 6, 
                                                                'Proposal/Price Quote' => 7, 
                                                                'Negotiation/Review' => 8, 
                                                                'Closed Won' => 9, 
                                                                'Closed Lost' => 9};
            
public void stageCannotBeMovedBackward(Map<Id, Opportunity> newMap, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap) {   

        for(Opportunity opp : newMap.values()) {
                Opportunity oldOpp = oldMap.get(opp.Id);
                if(stageValue.containsKey(opp.stageName) &&  stageValue.containsKey(oldOpp.stageName)
                        && stageValue.get(opp.stageName) < stageValue.get(oldOpp.stageName)) {
                        opp.addError('Error : Stage can not be moved backward');
                }    

 
        }
    
}
```

You can also do this via a validation rule. Here is the formula:

```
CASE(StageName, 
"Prospecting", 1, 
"Qualification", 2, 
"Needs Analysis", 3, 
"Value Proposition", 4, 
"Id. Decision Makers", 5, 
"Perception Analysis", 6, 
"Proposal/Price Quote", 7, 
"Negotiation/Review", 8, 
"Closed Won", 9, 
"Closed Lost", 10, 
0) 
< 
CASE(PRIORVALUE(StageName), 
"Prospecting", 1, 
"Qualification", 2, 
"Needs Analysis", 3, 
"Value Proposition", 4, 
"Id. Decision Makers", 5, 
"Perception Analysis", 6, 
"Proposal/Price Quote", 7, 
"Negotiation/Review", 8, 
"Closed Won", 9, 
"Closed Lost", 10, 
0)
```

Then set the required error message.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I stuck it on, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Where you are stuck please give more information

Comment: Added pictures of errors to body I'd appreciate it if you watched it.

Comment: I solved it. thank you